# Ошибка OCCI Oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, gcc

Поключаюсь к Oracle из C++.

Если я пишу приложение, то нормально... А если пишу статическую библиотеку, то на этот код:

```
#include <occi.h>
Enviroment *env;
```

выдаёт ошибку: 'Enviroment' does not name a type.

Может какие-то настройки указать нужно?

Comment: А посмотреть, где Environment объявляется вам самостоятельно не по силам?

Comment: Объявил же, в коде выше выложил...

Comment: Что вы объявили? Вы имя Environment объявили? Честно говоря, я вообще не понимаю, как можно заниматься программированием, используя имя, и не зная, где оно объявляется.

Comment: Его что нельзя тут объявлять чтоли?

Comment: @sitev_А вы его не объявляли. Вы его уже используете, как будто бы это имя уже объявлено в вашей единице компиляции. Вот я и спрашиваю, где оно объявлено и что означает?

Comment: http://cpp.sh/8y6i - работает же

Comment: Environment - это класс OCCI

Comment: class   Environment     
{
 public:
                    // class constants
...

Comment: Очевидно, что компилятор не видит объявление этого класса. Поэтому вы должны указать компилятору, где это имя объявлено. Например, может быть это имя объявлено в каком-то пространстве имен.

Comment: #include <occi.h>

Comment: А какое пространство имен?

Comment: ну да в этом и была ошибка "using namespace oracle::occi;" - теперь работает

Comment: Всё равно, я думаю, когда начинается затык, казалось бы на пустом месте, как тут, лучше спросить на форуме, может кто ткнёт пальцем... Спасиб, Влад! )

Comment: Давайте закроем вопрос. Вы отметите мой ответ, а я ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, что сообщение компилятора означает, что он не видит объявление имени `Environment`, а потому не знает, что оно означает.

Вы должны включить в единицу компиляции соответствующий заголовок, где это имя объявлено, и если имя к тому же объявлено в некотором пространстве имен. помимо глобального пространства имен, то либо использовать квалифицированное имя, либо использовать `using` объявление, либо включить `using` директиву.